# Multiple children of a single parent process

Tags: c, linux, terminal

How do I use the waitpid() command here to wait for termination of its children and then show the PIDs.

```
for(int i=0; i < 5 ;i++)
{
    if(pid > 0)
    {
        pid = fork();
        c++;

        if(pid==0)
        {
            printf("child: %d \n",c);
            printf("child process with pid self %d \n", getpid());              


         }

    }
}
```

Comment: [Docs are here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) and [here (with example)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should refactor your loop like this:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
...
pid_t pid;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {
        printf("child process with pid %d\n", getpid());
        ...
        exit(0);
    } else if (pid > 0) {
        /* the child has been forked and we are in the parent */
    } else {
        /* could not fork child */
    }
}

int status;

while ((pid = waitpid(-1, &status, 0))) {
    if (pid == -1 && errno == ECHILD) {
        break;
    } else if (pid == -1) {
        perror("waitpid");
    } else if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
        printf("%d exited, status=%d\n", pid, WEXITSTATUS(status));
    } else if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
        printf("%d killed by signal %d\n", pid, WTERMSIG(status));
    } else if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
        printf("%d stopped by signal %d\n", pid, WSTOPSIG(status));
    } else if (WIFCONTINUED(status)) {
        printf("%d continued\n", pid);
    }
}
```

Note the inclusion of a call to `exit` at the end of the child block. This is needed in order to prevent the child from continuing the execution of the loop.

The second loop should run until all of the children have terminated.

Comment: correct. Just to add one thing, it is always nice to put if(pid==-1) to check if fork has been successfully made or not.

Comment: @koksalb: the `else` branch is intended for handling failure in my example.

Comment: I've copy pasted your code and it gives me an error at "if (errno == ECHILD) {"

undeclared (first use in this function)
      if (errno == ECHILD) {
          ^
Q.c:41:10: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
Q.c:41:19: error: ‘ECHILD’ undeclared (first use in this function)
      if (errno == ECHILD) {

Comment: @SunAns: `#include <errno.h>`

Comment: Okay, one more thing. The part where I'm supposed to print the PIDs of the terminated child, am I supposed to do that inside this "if (errno == ECHILD)"  since you said its this loop where the child is terminated one by one. Thanking you in advance!

Comment: @SunAns: please consider accepting the question if it solved your issue.

Comment: @SunAns the code proposed above includes the printing of each child's pid, in the first loop (`for`) ; the second loop(`while`) is for your parent process to wait for its children to exit the program safely, preventing to create any zombie process. It will print the pid of each child, along with information on their exit status, and whether their were killed/stopped by a signal or not.